# Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-laser-drivers

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys
i want to use hokuyo-04lx but when i write
"sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-laser-drivers"
this error occured
"Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-laser-drivers"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77021/unable-to-locate-package-ros-fuerte-laser-drivers/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2013-09-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-07**:
Can we have some more information about how you have configured your system? Is there a reason you choose to use an older version of ROS for example?

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-07**:
Hi Dereck
I'm beginner in ros
I just follow the Ubuntu install of ROS Hydro for Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-urg-node

In a terminal (don't type the '$'):
$ roscore

In another Terminal:
$ rosrun urg_node urg_node

In another Terminal:
$ rosrun rviz rviz

In rviz, you can use the 'add' button on the lower left of the screen to add a display
I think you want to use pointcloud or pointcloud2 but you should be able click around and find what you need.
Then you just need to set the topic for the display to /laserscan and rviz should show you the laserscan data on the screen.

This is all off the top of my head however, and I don't have that specific Hokuyo. Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-07**:
Welcome to the wonderfully complex world of ROS. :) In hydro, the laser-drivers stack has been removed in favor or device specific packages, urg-node is the official driver for all Hokuyo devices.

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-07**:
thanks a lot :)

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-07**:
On sites like this, you can say thanks by clicking the small check-circle to the left of a correct answer and 'up-voting' if you have enough reputation. :)

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-07**:
hi  again
i test the laser scanner 04lx but this error occurd
[rospack] Error: stack/package hokuyo_node not found

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-08**:
In Hydro hokuyo_node driver was replaced with urg_node.

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-08**:
i write "rosrun urg_node urg_node"
but this error occurd again
[rospack] Error: stack/package urg_node not found
what can i do?

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-09**:
Unfortunately, ROS is not like most applications where you can just figure things out by poking it. I highly recommend you take a week to do the tutorials listed @ http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials They are terse, but will save you days of trouble. :)

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-09**:
when i wrote "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-urg-node"did it install the hokuyo pkg?
for install hokuyo pkg should i do anything more?

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-09**:
yes, that should have installed it. check /opt/ros/hydro/lib and you should see a urg_node directory.

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-09**:
I see urg_node but when i write "rospack find urg_node"
this error occurd again
"[rospack] Error: stack/package urg_node not found"
are sure that the name of the package that include urg_node is urg_node?

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-09**:
in "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks" i don't have urg_node stack,i just have these ones:

bullet            geometry_tutorials    robot_model_tutorials
common            laser_assembler       robot_model_visualization
common_rosdeps    laser_filters         simulator_gazebo
common_tutorials  laser_pipeline        slam_gmapping
documentation     navigation            stage
executive_smach   navigation_tutorials  visualization_tutorials
filters           physics_ode           xacro

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-10**:
you shouldn't have a urg_node in /stacks, urg_node is a catkin package and ROS is moving away from the /stacks architecture. It seems to me that your enviornment is not configured properly. You need to run 'source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash' in your terminal before launching urg_node.

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-10**:
i wrote it and terminal writes "ROS_DISTRO was set to 'groovy' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions."

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-10**:
open ~/.bashrc and replace any instances of 'groovy' with 'hydro' Then restart your terminal.

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-10**:
i edit "~/.bashrc" and i change "source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash" to "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash"
but when i type rosrun ... the terminal write "rosrun: command not found" but roscore works properly

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-10**:
when you installed, did you use 'sudo apt-get intstall ros-hydro-desktop-full' ?
When you run roscore, what is the version reported?

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-10**:
i don't know but i write this"sudo apt-get intstall ros-hydro-desktop-full" this error occurd "E: Invalid operation intstall" and my roscore verion is "ros_comm version 1.9.48"

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-10**:
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full

typo on my part, sorry

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-10**:
sorry!! but i don't understand your comment

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-10**:
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full  <-- note that the command is 'install' not 'intstall'

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-10**:
my net speed  is too low for download 607 MB it's take several hours i'll download and test it
and then write here the results

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-10**:
when i write "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full" the terminal write "Need to get 16.8 MB/161 MB of archives." and when i write "y" the terminal can't download .the terminal write several like this"Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-hydro-rqt-msg/ros-hydro-rqt-msg_0.3.0-0quantal-20130829-0900-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found"
and at the end write "E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-10**:
try 'sudo apt-get update'  and then try again. Perhaps the packages have been updated since you're last update? *shrug*

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-10**:
tnx a lot Derek :D in my country when one person want to thank some one says "The GOD give you the best in the world and in the other world" :D

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-10**:
:) I assume you got it working? Congratulations!

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-10**:
sorry Derek!! but I have some trouble :( first when i connect the laser and run urg_node this error occured
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what():  vector::_M_fill_insert Aborted (core dumped)"

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-10**:
and my second problem i wrote one program in ros and work  properly but now the program has one error
the error is "fatal error: turtlesim/Velocity.h: No such file or directory"

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-10**:
and one more question what difference between groovy an hydro?

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-11**:
You should ask new questions for those now that you have urg_node installed and running. :)

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2014-09-27**:
When I run rviz in the Global Status I get an error saying:
Fixed Frame
No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist
I try adding pointcloud display and changed its topic to /laserscan but nothing happens. Can anyone help?